# Is it possible to use type submit event as component in a multipage web application

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js13

I will start by explaining my folder structure to understand the problem I Have.
Folder Structure:

```markdown
app
 |--Todo
     |--page.tsx //where todo(s) will be created
 |--layout.tsx //global layout
 |--page.tsx //Main page were todo(s) will be viewed
components
 |--button.tsx //shared component that will be used throughout the whole app.
 |--header.tsx //header component
```

The button component is as follows: `button.tsx`

```js
export default function Button(props:any){
  return <input type={props.submit} value={props.value} />
}
```

The header component is as follows: `header.tsx`

```js
export default function Header(props:any){
  return <div>{props.children}</div>
}
```

Then the todo Page: `àpp/todo/page.tsx`

```js
export default function TodoPage(){

const [todo, setTodo] = useState("");

 function saveTodo(){
   console.log(todo);
 }
 
 function todoHandler(e:any){
  const value = e.target.value;

  setTodo(value);
}

 return (
  <form onSubmit={saveTodo}>
   <div >
     <input type="text" placeholder="Todo Title" value={todoHandler} />
   </div>
  </form>
 )
}
```

Now the important part is the layout page, I'm going to share the layout with different page routes. I had the following in mind:

```js
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header>
          <h1>New Todo</h1>
          <Button value={"Save Todo"} />
        </Header>
        {children} //The rest of the page routes will render here.
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Conclusion, what I'm trying to achieve is to use the `Header`component as a global view with the `Button` component in it. I will have multiple routes in the future and didn't want to import the same button on every new page.

When I ran the above result and check my console, nothing is happening. However when I import and using the `Button` component within the `todo/page.tsx` file it works flawlessly. I wanted to find out if i'm missing something or is it impossible to use the above method which i want to try.

Here's a diagram that I've included to help you understand what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Example Diagram]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give an id to your form

```
<form id="todo" onSubmit={saveTodo}>
  <div >
   <input type="text" placeholder="Todo Title" value={todoHandler} />
  </div>
</form>
```

Then target it with the "form" attribute on your input

```
export default function Button(props:any){
  return <input type={props.submit} value={props.value} form="todo" />
}
```

You may want to pass a "form" prop and change it depending on your current form of course

Comment: Thank you for the answer, do mind sharing some information on where to read more about the suggested solution you've just given me. I'm interested in learning and understanding what's going on.

Comment: Sure, take a look at the form attribute here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button (works for both button type="submit" and input type="submit")